# Hybris version upgrade - handle OOTB model's removed attribute

Tags: upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud

What is the best way to handle OOTB model's removed attribute?

In hybris version 6.6, there is `bundleNo` attribute in `AbstractOrderEntryModel`, then we're upgrading our hybris version, and we found out that on 1905, bundleNo attribute is no longer there. So do we have to re-add bundleNo attribute to `AbstractOrderEntryModel` or should we use another OOTB attribute that's available, considering in 6.6 we have some data using that attribute?

Thanks

Comment: in general attributes should not be removed in the OOTB product (due to potential migration issues). Can you point me to the extension where bundleNo attribute is defined in 6.6 ? Its not part of the core platform and might have come in from another extension that has since been removed

Comment: @Sebastian it's part of configurablebundleservices extension, it's being deprecated since 6.4, and being removed in 1905

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `bundleNo` attribute is deprecated since the 6.4 version, `entryGroupNumbers` should be used instead for the recent versions, it supports a set of ids now :

https://help.sap.com/doc/a4265d5ea8314eb2929e6cf6fb8e35a5/1811/en-US/de/hybris/platform/core/model/order/AbstractOrderEntryModel.html

Comment: How about existing data, should we do any migration to newer `entryGroupNumbers`?

Comment: Yes you should consider migrating data to the newer attribute

Comment: Well, that's the problem then, changing code is not a problem, migrating data is

Comment: Then use SQL queries to export-import data directly from your database

Comment: The problem is, bundleNo is Integer, while entryGroupNumbers is Set of Integer

Comment: but it should be possible to migrate the old "single" integer into the set of integers, no?